# WCF Calling Service with a large message

Tags: wcf

I'm calling a method of WCF Service. The method pass a graph within image to the service.

All calls throw an exception saying:

```
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request
```

I have read many posts concerning this problem, most of them suggest to increase the maxReceivedMessageSize. I tried to modify this and other settings but it doesn't solved the problem.

Finally I have activated tracing on server which says:

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
```

The value in my config file is set to 65536000.

My Config File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="false">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="C:\Trace\messages.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add initializeData="C:\Trace\tracelog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
      <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true"
        messageFlowTracing="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Beh">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000000"/>
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
          sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="65536000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288000"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="500000000" maxStringContentLength="500000000"
            maxArrayLength="500000000" maxBytesPerRead="500000000" maxNameTableCharCount="500000000" />
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="WcfService1.PleasureKraftService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="Beh" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WebBinding" name="Basic" contract="WcfService1.IMyService"
          listenUriMode="Explicit">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="WcfService1.IMyService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false"/>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Ent" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=Eu;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't know how to fix the problem from your last message. We use a different binding at my company, and we set the `max...Size` attributes on our `httpTransport`. I have deleted my answer so that your question would get more attention as unanswered.

Comment: I think that WCF does not read my binding configuration for some reason but place default one in place of it. Thank you for trying.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to define the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on both the client and the service.

Comment: I agree, I think the client is getting a bigger message than it expects.

Comment: MaxReceivedMessageSize settings on client does not matter, the image is passed from client to the server not the other way around. As I understand you need to up size this property on client in case you are getting large responses from the server.

Comment: Also, to make 100% sure: The settings on client are same and I have no problem to get exactly same data on client.

Answer (score 0):

1. Increase message max quota, probably timeout as well depending on message size - you can do so declaratively, or programmatically as shown below.

   BasicHttpBinding Binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

   ```
   Binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(???, 0, 0);
   Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(???, 0, 0);
   Binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(???, 0, 0);
   Binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(???, 0, 0);

   Binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = ???;
   Binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = ???;
   Binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = ???;
   Binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = ???;
   Binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = ???;
   Binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = ???;
   ```
2. Splits your payload into smaller chunks

**OPTION 1:** Chunk your payload yourself

**OPTION 2:** Channel chunking
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050(v=vs.110).aspx